# How to avoid snapshot while refactoring with xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, refactoring

Whenever I extract my code using Refactor >> Extract or Refactor >> Rename, Xcode creates snapshot of code but its slowing the speed of extraction. So to work more efficiently I want to disable this snapshot on every refactor. Does anyone know from where I can get that option in Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some investigation I found that option myself. If anyone wants to disable snapshot and save time while refactoring, here's is option:

File >> Project Settings >> Snapshot >> Deselect this option: Create snapshot of project before mass-editing operations

Here you can also change snapshot location if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Under File > Project Settings, select the Snapshots tab and unselect "Create snapshots of project before mass-editing operations":

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I got that option myself too xD